# Remove margin from first item only in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` with different sections and Headers for each, `Video`, `Audio`, `Image`.

Using a `XAML` `Style`, I added a `7px` margin above the Headers to space the sections apart.

How can I remove only the first Header's margin, so it is flush against the top of the `ComboBox`?

I tried setting the `ComboBox` `<Grid>` to `Margin="0,-7,0,0"` but it applied to all items.

[image: ComboBox Header Margins]

---

#### ComboBox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboContainer" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Format_Container_Items}"
          SelectedValuePath="Name"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Format_Container_SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxCustom}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ComboBoxCustomItem}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="105" 
          Height="22"
          Margin="0,2,0,0">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding}">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <Binding Path="Name"/>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

#### Item Style

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxCustomItem" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxCustom.Item.ControlTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <Style.Triggers>

        <!-- Selected -->
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxCustom.Static.Foreground}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxCustom.Static.Background}" />
        </Trigger>

        <!-- Mouse Over -->
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxCustom.MouseOver.Foreground}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxCustom.MouseOver.Background}" />
        </Trigger>

        <!-- Headers -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHeader}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <!-- 7px Margin Applied Here -->
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,7,0,0"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHeader}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        </DataTrigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

#### Items Source

```
public class FormatContainer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsHeader { get; set; }
}

public List<FormatContainer> _Format_Container_Items = new List<FormatContainer>()
{
    new FormatContainer() { Name = "Video", IsHeader = true  },
    new FormatContainer() { Name = "webm",  IsHeader = false },
    new FormatContainer() { Name = "mp4",   IsHeader = false },
    new FormatContainer() { Name = "mkv",   IsHeader = false },

    new FormatContainer() { Name = "Audio", IsHeader = true  },
    new FormatContainer() { Name = "mp3",   IsHeader = false },
    new FormatContainer() { Name = "m4a",   IsHeader = false },
    new FormatContainer() { Name = "ogg",   IsHeader = false },

    new FormatContainer() { Name = "Image", IsHeader = true  },
    new FormatContainer() { Name = "jpg",   IsHeader = false },
    new FormatContainer() { Name = "png",   IsHeader = false },
    new FormatContainer() { Name = "webp",  IsHeader = false },
};

public List<FormatContainer> Format_Container_Items
{
    get { return _Format_Container_Items; }
    set
    {
        _Format_Container_Items = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Format_Container_Items");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could set the `margin` at the end of a item. Like `Margin="0 0 0 7"`

Comment: @Cizzl yes but then he would need to set it only to the last item of each section, so the problem is still here

Comment: You can try to use `AlternationIndex` of ComboBox in datatrigger to setup the style of your first item. Or implement one more property inside Container. Or use XAML converter as answer below follows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the question itself, All you need is a `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

```
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0 -7 0 0"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
```

But for the right way to do what you want, I strongly recommand you change you data struct to

```
public class FormatContainer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

then group the view of `Format_Container_Items` with `Category` and use ComboBox.GroupStyle to customize the presentation.

Answer (score 2):

If I was doing this in a commercial app I'd probably expose a property in my FormatContainer to indicate to the view which element in the list is first, but it can be done in XAML with the use of an equality converter that returns true when any two items are the same:

```
public class EqualityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Object.Equals(values[0], values[1]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then back in your XAML you just add an extra DataTrigger using this as the converter and passing in both the current object and the first one in the original list:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <conv:EqualityConverter />
            </MultiBinding.Converter>
            <Binding Path="DataContext.Format_Container_Items[0]" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}" />
            <Binding />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

I really would recommend you handle this in your view model though using a regular DataTrigger. Techniques like the one I've used here show off the power of the WPF binding engine, but at the end of the day you're still adding logic code to view layer which is not where it really belongs, even if it is a generic converter.

Answer (score 2):

You can define another property like *IsFirstHeader* and add the margin only to it.

Comment: I would say `IsNotFirstHeader` and add margins to all headers except first.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work when applied as style trigger, but have a try.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
</DataTrigger>
```